# PlotLabels by numbers when plot a list of function

Tags: plotting, labeling

I have a list of functions, the length of the list is not sure.
Maybe be just like:

```
f = {x, x^2, x^3, x^4};
Plot[f, {x, 0, 2}, PlotLabels -> {"1","2","3","4"}]
```

I want they are labeled by the function number, when I know the total number, I will give labels by hand (I think not good way), but if I don't know the total number, how to automatic show labels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f]
f = {x, x^2, x^3, x^4};


Plot[f, {x, 0, 2}, PlotLabels -> Range[Length@f]] (* or *)

Plot[Evaluate@MapIndexed[Callout[#, #2[[1]]] &, f], {x, 0, 2}] (* or *)

Plot[Evaluate@MapIndexed[Labeled[#, #2[[1]]] &, f], {x, 0, 2}] (* or *)
```

all give

[image]

Comment: Or adding `Tooltip`: `Plot[f, {x, 0, 2}, 
 PlotLabels -> (Tooltip[#, f[[#]]] & /@ Range@Length@f)]`